# unique email validation is not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:connection.tmp_customers,email',
```

Error is Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: Are you using a custom database connection?

Comment: Yes, i'm using a custom database connection

Answer (score 0):

**try this way**

```
'email'=> 'required|email|unique:p66_vender,email',
```

**another way**

```
$data->email = $request->get('email')->unique('email');
```